# PHP exec() timeout on Windows

Tags: php, timeout, exec

I can't find a properly solution for timing-out php's exec() function. I found a code `http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/08/24/execute-with-timeout.html` but i don't know how to make it work on windows. Is this possible? I've tried some solutions from php.net(code that used PStools) but it doesn't work either. So the question is, is there any solution to make timeout for executing commands on window (it would be better not to use external executables)? Also, important note - i need to get program output.

First issue is that windows do not have 'exec' command:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '"exec" не является вну
тренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
' in C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\timeout.php:71
```

It says that there is no internal or external programm, or file.

Comment: what problem do you have with this code on windows exactly (post the output or a screenshot), this could help to solve the problem